# C# Regex parsing HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex

My Value 1

I need "My Value 1" Please Help Me. C# language

Comment: will the tags always be in the same format (eg 3 layers deep with a tr, a td and a font)

Comment: What language are you using to parse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# language

```
 string input = "<tr><TD><FONT size=\"2\">My Value 1</FONT></TD></tr>";
 string pattern = @"<[^>]*?>";
 string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, ""); //My Value 1
```

Just to remove all html tags.

Answer (score 7):

As HTML code is very "unpredictable" I would recommend using a HTML parsing kit. Which programming language do you use? In .NET I have used [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) with great success. In Java [HTML Parse](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)r might be handy (though I have not worked with it yet).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot properly parse HTML with regular expressions because regexps can't handle the nesting allowed by HTML. To do it properly. For that one line you show, you can use a regexp but you can't count on that line remaining identical so must use SAX/DOM for the task generally.

Comment: But you can parse a fixed string that happens to be HTML with regular expressions. While there are lots of issues with doing this, they're problems the OP probably doesn't have.

Comment: @Tom - agreed. But although the OP doesn't have them today, he might tomorrow and won't be left wondering what happened, hopefully.

Answer (score 3):

I think parsing HTML using Regexes is not a wise idea, as highlighted by spa. 
A classic previous answer to a similar question is [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/<tr>\s*<td>\s*<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/i
```

Used in PHP:

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/<tr>\s*<td>\s*<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/i',
              '<tr><TD><FONT size="2">My Value 1</FONT></TD></tr>',$matches))
        echo $matches[1]; // prints My Value 1
?>
```

Comment: @codaddict i need c# language :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripTags(markup){
  return markup.replace(/\s*<[^>]*?>\s*/gim,'');
}
```

This assumes all you really want is the inner text represented by "My Value 1" above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PHP, split on `</FONT>`

```
$string='<tr><TD><FONT size="2">My Value 1</FONT></TD></tr>';
$s = explode('</FONT>',$string);
foreach ($s as $v){
     if ( strpos($v,"<FONT") !==FALSE) {
        $t = explode(">",$v);
        print end($t)."\n";
    }

}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
My Value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in perl I would use

```
my $string='<tr><TD><FONT size="2">My Value 1</FONT></TD></tr>';
$string =~ m/(<.*?>)*([^<]*)(<.*?>)*/;
print $2;
```

to get the desired result. The last part is not strictly necessary,

```
(<.*?>)*([^<]*)
```

will work as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents within the tags I think the following Regexp is enough:

```
^<.*>([^<>]+)<.*>$
```

It will only work if there really is any data between the tags somewhere, otherwise it will give a no-match.

Comment: i need only value "My Value 1"